# Guest link via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I would know if exist a way to generate a guest link for a file stored on sharepoint 2013 online via Rest api and access token. I tried this link passing the access token but doesn't work if you are not logged in.

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/aclinv.aspx?obj={12311-123a-4123-ef123-asdf31ef},16,DOCUMENT&List=12311-123a-4123-ef123-asdf31ef&command=createlink&readwrite=true
```

Comment: Without logged in SharePoint will never be able to find whether the user who is going to share has the necessary permissions. Hence Login is very much required in this case.

Comment: I think a scope and right able to give you the authorization to request a edit link exist...because when I try to make this request I receive Aunatorize